# Unable to drop any build activity onto build sequence diagram

Tags: msbuild, build-process, build-automation, tfsbuild

I have a strange problem with build process designer in VS 2010.

I have checked out a build process template for edit and opened it in the designer. I want to modify the workflow but I'm unable to drop any build activity onto the design surface. 
I have only built-in activities installed. None errors and warnings are visible in Error list window. I'm able to modify activities which already exists on the diagram. I tried to restart Visual Studio, reopen the designer and create a brand new template but I have the same result in every case. The strangest part is that around two weeks ago it worked correctly. I created custom build templates with success then.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I did a right-click on the sequence surface and noticed an option called "Open". I selected this option and now I'm able to add new activities onto the diagram. It is a bit strange anyway because my project members are able to modify the diagram without selecting that option.